# Overage Authenticated Website User Profile has no custom object permission section

Tags: force.com-sites, licenses

I was going through the Overage Authenticated Website User Profile and found that it doesnt have any section for Custom Object Permission. So tried to clone the same but still I cant see the section for the custom Objects. Some how only the Standard Object permission was available.

[image]

Any Idea what needs to be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it my self.
If you have a look at the custom object definition. You can find a checkbox that says "Available for Customer Portal". This controls the visibility of the custom object @ Customer Portal Profile.

[image]